# android Listview with spinner

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-spinner

I have layout1.xml file having one `spinner` and one `TextView`, 
and also I have another layout2.xml that includes a `ListView`.

Now I have a set of array items presenting in strings.xml
that I have made into `ArrayList` in my present logic, 
now I have written custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`, 
I will set custom adapter, in which taking `ArrayList` count based on that `getView()` method will work, so that every `ListView` has name based on position, with spinner.

Spinner has common values in every `ListView` position  eg:(yes,no), 
now I am not able to retrieve this spinner value with `TextView` value

Comment: Please clarify your question. Code with clear problem description is often helpful.

Comment: your Question is not clear. Also show some code which you tried.